# How to center li tags using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, html-lists

Im working on a website and want to create a custom list with embedded pictures as links. 
[Here](http://www.skyvueranchalpacas.com/) is a link to the website:

I want the links to rearrange left justified based on browser size and the pictures to resize based on browser size.

I'm getting it to re-size based on browser size, but for the life of me i cant get the product centered on a mobile device and certain browser sizes.

Here is the current HTML/CSS I am using for this.

thanks in advance for your help.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="home-page">
<ul class="tile">
<li id="one"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://www.skyvueranchalpacas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Alpaca-Test.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li id="two"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://www.skyvueranchalpacas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Alpaca-Test.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li id="three"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://www.skyvueranchalpacas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Alpaca-Test.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li id="four"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://www.skyvueranchalpacas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Alpaca-Test.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Home page Tiles
*/

/* tiles as a whole */

.post-475 page type-page status-publish entry{
}

div.home-page{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
}

.tile{
    float: left;
position: relative;
display: block;
text-align: center;
background: none;
font-size: 20px;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-left: -40px;
line-height: 1em;
padding-left: 10px;

}
/* indavidual list */
.tile li{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
background: none;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 60px;
padding:0 10px;

}
/* List Picture (before click) */
.tile li img {
max-width: 22em;
width: 100%;
height: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can centralize the `<li>`s with just this cahnge in your `CSS` for `.entry-content ul`. Just replace that with the below given one.

```
.entry-content ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: this seemed to of helped. however on lower wisth browsers (such as phones, the list is still not centering.

Comment: why would this be happening?

Comment: Try removing the padding from `.title`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.tile{
   /* float: left;*/
position: relative;
display: block;
text-align: center;
background: none;
font-size: 20px;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-left: -40px;
line-height: 1em;
padding-left: 10px;

}
/* indavidual list */
li{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
background: none;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 60px;
padding:0 10px;
```

Use `li` instead of `.title li`. Also, the `float:left;` declaration might be negating the `text-align:center;` one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="home-page">` has a `margin-left: 20%` and is causing the list not to center. Use a media query to fix this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em){
    div.home-page{
    margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

I didn't do a ton of testing on this but it fixes the issue for me.

Good luck!

Comment: I also noticed on your `.entry-content ul{` you have `margin-left: 0, auto` this is incorrect. You can only pass one value into margin-left so I would change this to `.entry-content ul{ margin: 0 auto; text-align-center;}` and you may get the behavior your actually looking for as well.